# How to use a vbscript for a specific process?

Tags: vbscript

Well, I didn't found anything about it so there is my doubt... I have found this code that do something in a loop but is incomplete to me, look,

```
set shl = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
wscript.sleep(5000)
Do Until foo = 34
    shl.sendkeys"{Enter}"
    wscript.sleep(1000)
    shl.sendkeys"/Reset"
    wscript.sleep(1000)
    shl.sendkeys"{Enter}"
    wscript.sleep(180000)
Loop
```

Here is the problem, for this to work the window should be in focus and what I want is that it can be minimized.

Thank you.

Comment: What program do you want to be focused before you send the keys?

Comment: @BoffinbraiN, Well, I want to do other tasks while the script will be runing so I can see in another monitor, this, without disturbing me. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Activates an application window.
>
> Syntax
>
> ---
>
> Copier
>
> object.AppActivate title
>
> Arguments
>
> ---
>
> object WshShell object. title Specifies which application to activate.
>   This can be a string containing the title of the application (as it
>   appears in the title bar) or the application's Process ID.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/wzcddbek(v=vs.84).aspx

Note use the statement before sending each sequence of keys. Also see documentation of when a program can set the foreground window in remarks at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: This is a alternative, but the window will be displayed on another monitor just for checking (not in focus) and the focus will be on other tasks.